# jQuery .css() returning pixels instead of percent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, so when I get a CSS property that's been stored as a percent using jQuery `.css()` it is returned with its pixel value. This is great for my purposes actually, I can use it...is it an intended result I will see consistently in all modern browsers both now and in the future, though?

I can't seem to find much info here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery doc

*The .css() method is a convenient way to get a style property from the first matched element, especially in light of the different ways browsers access most of those properties (the **getComputedStyle()** method in standards-based browsers versus the **currentStyle** and **runtimeStyle** properties in Internet Explorer) and the different terms browsers use for certain properties.*

yes it is an intended result

if you want to find the actual style value , you can do something like this,

```
var topValue = $("#mydiv")[0].style.top
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see this behaviour in all browsers both now and in future. Because this is how browsers render the `css property`. Scripting languages will get these details from the `DOM` after it got interpreted from the browser. So this is the natural behaviour and this wont change.

Additionally, `Percentages` will be converted into `pixels` based on the `element's parent` during rendering process. So that it will not display the css property in percentage while you retrieving that. You have to calculate it manually if you need it for sure.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the primary question: *"...is it an intended result I will see consistently in all modern browsers both now and in the future, though?"* (Not my dv)

Comment: T.J. is right...I understand what's going on and of course can convert pixels to percentages easily - for that reason I find this method of data return to be more useful and versatile.  I just want to know if I can count on its consistency.

Comment: @user3011922 Yes this will be consistent. I just added more details into my answer.

Comment: Cool, thank you! I was not the one who thumbed you down originally, but I did thumb you up now so you will at least be neutral.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered by the burgeoning [CSSOM specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/). In general, yes, you can rely on pixel values **provided** the `display` property is not set to `none`. [Section 9 of the above](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#resolved-values) has the details; for *most* properties where you'd expect a number (`width` and such), it says:

> If the property applies to the element or pseudo-element and the resolved value of the 'display' property is not 'none', the resolved value is the used value. Otherwise the resolved value is the computed value.

...where "resolved value" means (for these properties) a number of pixels rather than a relative amount (percentage and similar), which would be the "computed value" ("computed" as in "taking all style rules into consideration").

Supporting the case of this being (newly) specified behavior, when non-pixel values have been returned in various situations, bugs have been reported and accepted (in [WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29084), in [jQuery](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10639), in [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/ticket/2529799)).